# AR.JS with WebView iOS

Tags: swift, ar.js

I am testing AR.js in WebView of swift, but I get the following problem

```
WebcamError
Name:
Message: WebRTC issue-!
navigator.mediaDevices not present in your browser
```

But in safari AR.js works

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. iOS WebViews don't offer the APIs needed by AR.js to work.